# Convert a file into PDF with a Visual Basic script

Tags: vba, pdf

I'd like to know how to convert a file into PDF when I'm programming in VB. Do you have the script or if there is a pre-defined function, what is it's name?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of file are you starting out with? Text, Word, HTML, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : [Best Of Two Worlds - Acrobat PDF Scripting Using VisualBasic (VBA) & JavaScript](http://diaryproducts.net/for/programmer/adobe_acrobat_pdf_scripting_visualbasic_javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[`CutePDF`](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/Writer.asp) is free and works like an ordinary printer, so you can use the application's normal print commands.